# What should the LogoutUri be for a WebForms client using OpenIdConnect authentication?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, openid-connect, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 provider and I'm trying to connect an ASP.NET WebForms client to it using OIDC authentication. Everything is fine except I couldn't figure out what the `LogoutUri` should be. I've tried `/signout-oidc` or `/signout-callback-oidc` but neither seem to exist, they both return 404 error (interestingly `/signin-oidc` does exist). Should I add an [SignoutCleanup](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/signout-http.html).aspx logic and use that page as `LogoutUri` instead?

Here's the client and OIDC config:

```
{
                ClientId = "client.webforms",
                ClientName = "WebForms Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = false,

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:9869/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:9869/" },
                LogoutUri = "http://localhost:9869/signout-callback-oidc",

                AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        "test_scope"
                    },
                AllowOfflineAccess = false,
                RequireConsent = false,

                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
            });
```

...

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        AuthenticationType = "oidc",
                        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                        Authority = "http://localhost:3027/",
                        ClientId = "client.webforms",
                        RedirectUri = "http://localhost:9869/signin-oidc",
                        PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:9869/",
                        ResponseType = "id_token code",
                        Scope = "openid test_scope",
                        UseTokenLifetime = false,
                        ... (events)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Katana/WebForms has no built-in implementation of the signout endpoint.

Create an action on a controller that cleans up (e.g. deletes the authN cookie) - and use that address as a logout URI.

IdentityServer will pass the value of the sid claim to the logout endpoint - you should compare that with the sid claim you get at sign-in time to avoid logout spam.